# Name for set of disjunct sets spanning covering another space

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $X$ be a set and $Y$ a set of subsets of $X$, such that all elements of $Y$ are disjunct and the union of all elements of $Y$ equals $X$.
Is there a formal name for $Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a **partition** of $X$.
Note that partitions of $X$ are in one-to-one correspondence with *equivalence relations* on $X$.

Comment: Is there a name for this thing if each of the subsets is an open set? I do not want to include the "boundary" between the subsets. How would I define this? I cannot write that the union of all subsets covers X.

Comment: I'm not aware of any, but a name like '*open partition*' would do: pairwise disjoint open sets such that the union of their closures is the whole space.

Comment: Perfect, that'll do nicely! I forgot about the concept of closures.